# Repeatedly Play Audio on Sony Spresense

Tags: arduino, spresense

I'm trying to repeatedly play an audio file on the Sony Spresense. I have tested the example sketches provided by Sony and they work fine for playing an audio file. But if I want to replay the file, I get errors. Unfortunately, all sketches only play their file once...

To keep it simple, I have shrunk the source code.

```cpp
#include <Audio.h>
#include <SDHCI.h>

static void audioErrorCallback(const ErrorAttentionParam *atprm);
bool initializeSound();

SDClass theSD;
AudioClass *theAudio;
File soundFile;
bool soundFinished;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial);
  initializeSound();
  soundFinished = true;
}

void loop() {
  if (!soundFinished) {
    int err = theAudio->writeFrames(AudioClass::Player0, soundFile);
    if (err == AUDIOLIB_ECODE_FILEEND) {
      soundFinished = true;
      stopPlay();
    }
  } else {
    Serial.println("Sleep");
    delay(3000);
    soundFinished = false;
    startPlay();
  }
  usleep(40000);
}

static void audioErrorCallback(const ErrorAttentionParam *atprm) {
  if (atprm->error_code >= AS_ATTENTION_CODE_WARNING)
  {
    Serial.println("Error!");
  }
}

bool initializeSound() {
  theAudio = AudioClass::getInstance();
  theAudio->begin(audioErrorCallback);
  theAudio->setRenderingClockMode(AS_CLKMODE_NORMAL);
  theAudio->setPlayerMode(AS_SETPLAYER_OUTPUTDEVICE_SPHP, AS_SP_DRV_MODE_LINEOUT);
  theAudio->initPlayer(AudioClass::Player0, AS_CODECTYPE_MP3, "/mnt/sd0/BIN", AS_SAMPLINGRATE_AUTO, AS_CHANNEL_STEREO);
  soundFile = theSD.open("audioFile.mp3");
  theAudio->setVolume(-160);
  return true;
}

void startPlay() {
  theAudio->writeFrames(AudioClass::Player0, soundFile);
  theAudio->startPlayer(AudioClass::Player0);
}

void stopPlay() {
  theAudio->stopPlayer(AudioClass::Player0);
  // soundFile.close();

}
```

The audio file is played without problems for the first time. Afterwards, I receive the following error, always:

```
Attention: module[5] attention id[2]/code[6] (objects/media_player/player_input_device_handler.cpp L220)
Error!
ERROR: Command (0x22) fails. Result code(0xf1) Module id(0x5) Error code(0x2f) Error subcode(0x0)
ERROR: Command (0x23) fails. Result code(0xf1) Module id(0x5) Error code(0x1)
```

What's missing? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and I was able to fix it by closing the File at the end, and creating a new File at the the start of the loop() instead of in the setup() function.